# Copy specific fields by using BeanUtils.copyProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-commons

`springframework.beans.BeanUtils` is very useful to copy objects, and I use the "ignoreProperties" option frequently. However, sometimes I want to copy only specific objects (basically, the opposite of "ignore Properties"). Does anyone know how can I do that? Any help will be appreciated.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

public class Sample {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        DemoADto demoADto = new DemoADto();
        demoADto.setName("Name of Demo A");
        demoADto.setAddress("Address of Demo A");

        DemoBDto demoBDto = new DemoBDto();

        // This is "ignoreProperties" option
        // But I want to know how I can copy only name field by using BeanUtils or something.
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(demoADto, demoBDto, new String[] {"address"});

        System.out.println(demoBDto.getName());
        System.out.println(demoBDto.getAddress());    
    }    
}

public class DemoADto {    
    private String name;    
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }    
}

public class DemoBDto {    
    private String name;    
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use the [`BeanWrapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans) technology. Here's a sample implementation:

```
public static void copyProperties(Object src, Object trg, Iterable<String> props) {

    BeanWrapper srcWrap = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(src);
    BeanWrapper trgWrap = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(trg);

    props.forEach(p -> trgWrap.setPropertyValue(p, srcWrap.getPropertyValue(p)));

}
```

Or, if you really, *really* want to use `BeanUtils`, here's a solution. Invert the logic, gather excludes by comparing the full property list with the includes:

```
public static void copyProperties2(Object src, Object trg, Set<String> props) {
    String[] excludedProperties = 
            Arrays.stream(BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(src.getClass()))
                  .map(PropertyDescriptor::getName)
                  .filter(name -> !props.contains(name))
                  .toArray(String[]::new);

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, trg, excludedProperties);
}
```

Comment: BeanWrapper technology is 25% faster. :)

Comment: Spring recommends using `PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(Object)` instead.  [source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html)

Comment: how do you get Iterable<String> properties ?

Comment: @kiedysktos Iterable is an interface that is extended by Collection, so this method will accept any `Collection<String>`

Comment: Tip on BeanWrapper: use trgWrap.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(true) to avoid NullValueInNestedPathException

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Commons BeanUtils you can still use Spring by using the [BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html).

You will have to manually loop through all the properties so you will want to make a static helper method.

You can always just copy what copyProperties is doing and adjust to your liking:
http://tinyurl.com/BeanUtils-copyProperties

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [BeanPropertyCopyUtil](http://code.google.com/p/vineetmanohar/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/vineetmanohar/util/BeanPropertyCopyUtil.java).

Example:

```
copyProperties(user, systemUser, "first firstName", "last lastName");
```

You'll also need Apache Commons BeanUtils.

Comment: This is not appropriate way to achieve this. What if your attribute name modified ? passing it as string is not better approach, rather fetch all the fields using 

Field[] fields = destination.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

And iterate over the fields 
for (Field field : fields){
  //ur copy stuff here 
}

Comment: This is not working with child properties, let's say i wanted to ignore all properties with name "id".

Answer (score 2):

`beanUtils` has an overloaded method wherein we can pass an array of fields that we want to ignore.

Eg.

```
String[] ignoreProperties= new String[]{"field1","field2"};

BeanUtils.copyProperties(a, b,ignoreProperties);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use 
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target, Class editable) throws BeansException

Ensure the target implements the interface editable which defines the properties which would be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example with Spring BeanUtils class:

```
public static void copyList(List sourceList,
        List targetList, Class targetType) {

    try {

        for (Object source : sourceList) {
            Object target = null;
            target = targetType.newInstance();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
            targetList.add(target);
        }

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```